# How do I secure a dishwasher under a granite counter?

Tags: dishwasher, granite

I purchased some Loctite power grab yesterday in hopes to attach my dishwasher to the granite countertop that it has not adhered to very well with just caulk. I'm having second thoughts, now, since this is a bonding agent that may cause permanent damage (perhaps not as bad as screwing directly into the countertop, but you understand what I'm saying).

Are my hesitations correct? Should I use something different? What should I use?

It looks like the person who attached the washer in before used a silicone caulk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two good options with a stone counter top if there isn't a mounting strip already under the countertop.

- Option 1: Install a mounting strip under the counter, going all the way to the side cabinets and securing with some adhesive to the underside of the countertop (I've heard silicon suggested, but I'd prefer something stronger). I'd also use a couple L brackets to secure the mounting strip to the side cabinets. Then use short screws to attach the dishwasher so you don't go through the mounting strip and into the countertop. This doesn't work if you're already tight for space between the dishwasher and countertop.
- Option 2: Get a side mounting kit to attach the dishwasher to the cabinets on each side. It may be a separate purchase from the manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks! Mounting strip was not on my radar until you mentioned it.

Answer (score 2):

Side mounting kits are a pain in the butt.  You can use those but I think they are overkill.

Your dishwasher mainly needs to keep from tipping over when you pull out a heavy rack.  All dishwashers come with front mounting brackets.  These can be attached to the bottom of stone.  Silicone is a short-term answer.  A little "knife grade epoxy" is what you need to make it permanent.  The downside of the epoxy is that it is hard to find at local stores.

Comment: But would the epoxy come off when it's time to replace the appliance?